# what is the MY_UUID used as a parameter in device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID) in android bluetooth api

Tags: android, bluetooth

i m still a beginner in android and i want to make a bluetooth connection but while reading the offecial android documentation i didn't understood MY_UUID used as a parameter  in device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID)  in android bluetooth api  ? and why when i  add this thread in my app i got the 
     manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket) with red color .

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
        manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are connecting to some device you did not build yourself, you need to use one of his **UUID**.

```
  ParcelUuid[] idArray = device.getUuids();  
  java.util.UUID uuidYouCanUse = java.util.UUID.fromString(idArray[i].toString());
```

You may need to figure which Uuid corresponds to which device feature by yourself.
You will fail to connect with some Uuid, but succeed with the others.

2. If you are the creator of the server and the client side applications, then UUID is the value **YOU** create and use in both applications when designing connections.

```
java.util.UUID myOwnUUID = UUID.randomUUID();  
String stringVersionOfUUID = myOwnUUID.toString();
```